# I can't compile AppCompat-v7 to my Android Studio Project

Tags: android, gradle, build, compilation

i am having a strange issue which stops me from developing further my app.
I need to make an UI with a Viewpager and some tabs (TabLayout) and in order to achieve this i need to compile android design and appcompat libraries.
But here's the problem, it keeps telling me that "ColorAccent" is already defined with an incompatible format.

I have tried everything i could to repair but it seems like it won't work. Had anyone solved this ? Please help!

here's my error log:

```
~ my path at MyApp's directory app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(148) Attribute "colorAccent" already defined with incompatible 
format.
Error:(3) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(148) Attribute "colorAccent" already defined with incompatible 
format.
Error:(3) Original attribute defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

**EDIT:** Here's my build code:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "tap.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1"
compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1"
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Show your full app level gradle file (what you have under "build code").

Comment: @DanielNugent check the edits please

Comment: Try it with `buildToolsVersion "24.2.1"`   Also remove both lines where you have `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'`  They are not needed since the appcompat v7 library automatically imports the support v4 library.  also, it might be conficting with the annotations compile (leave that one there)

Comment: @DanielNugent thank you for your answer, i'll try it now, and i'll come with feedback

Comment: @DanielNugent i tried it but it says : Install build tools 24.2.1 and sync project, after i click this, it shows me All packages are not available for download!

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**: what i was doing wrong is that i declared a colorAccent variable inside my attributes xml (attrs.xml), so the gradle couldn't compile the library due to a possible duplicate of that specific value (color Accent). Removing that value fixed what i was doing wrong for hours.